# In Revelation 7:9, do people keep their racial features?

Tags: revelation

Revelation 7:9

> After this I looked, and there before me was a great multitude that no one could count, from every **nation**, **tribe**, people and language, standing before the throne and before the Lamb. They were wearing white robes and were holding palm branches in their hands.

nation
ἔθνους (ethnous)
Noun - Genitive Neuter Singular
Strong's Greek 1484: Probably from etho; a **race**, i.e. A tribe; specially, a foreign one.

tribe
φυλῶν (phylōn)
Noun - Genitive Feminine Plural
Strong's Greek 5443: A tribe or **race** of people. From phuo; an offshoot, i.e. Race or clan.

Does this mean that they will keep their skin color in heaven at this scene in Revelation 7:9?

Comment: Are you asking about the new Heaven on the new Earth [Revelation 21:1-2] ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the same setting. I welcome answers from Rev 21 if it sheds light on Rev 7.

Comment: I personally do not care - I am far more concerned about being there than what people look like.

Comment: If the first heaven and earth pass away, as we can read in one of the answers, they are gone. To pass away = to die. If so, it wouldn’t make much of a difference where the New Earth is being located. If at the same spot as the old earth, or somewhere else. Although it is probably more plausible that the location is elsewhere, at a less dangerous spot. Because the big earth destroying phenomenon that made the old earth pass away would be too close to the New Earth to assure eternal existence otherwise.

Comment: A guess is that the 24 elders has something to do with the populating of the New Earth. A space/time machine, and maybe cloning, would have to be involved also somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Will humans keep their skin color in the New Heaven (in the place called יְהוָ֥ה שָֽׁמָּה) on the new Earth? - Yes. | Based on the accounts of Revelation 21:1-2 & Ezekiel 47-48 [MT].

**Revelation 21:1-4** [NASB]

> "Then **I saw a new heaven and a new earth; for the first heaven and the first earth passed away, and there is no longer any sea. 2 And I saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God**, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. 3 And I heard a loud voice from the throne, saying, **“Behold, the tabernacle of God is among the people, and He will dwell among them, and they shall be His people, and God Himself will be among them,** 4 and He will wipe away every tear from their eyes; and there will no longer be any death; there will no longer be any mourning, or crying, or pain; the first things have passed away.”

**In Ezekiel 48, the prophet יְחֶזְקֵ֨אל Yechezqel lists the names of the tribes who will welcome stranger sojourners as citizens among the children of Yisrael in the place called "YHVH [is its] Name". - Thus in the new Heaven, humans on earth (with visible skin color) will dwell together as One in the place called יְהוָ֥ה שָֽׁמָּה.**

Answer (score 1):

Revelation 7:9

After this, I looked, and there before me was a great multitude that no one could count, from every nation, tribe, people, and language, standing before the throne and before the Lamb. They were wearing white robes and were holding palm branches in their hands.

In Revelation 7:9, do people keep their racial features?

**Yes they would keep their racial features.**

Their position is figurative, even though they would live on earth, the great multitude would stand before the throne and before the Lamb, indicates that they have favored recognition before God.  The fact that they are “dressed in white robes,” signifies that they have kept themselves “without spot” from Satan’s world and have remained loyal to God and Christ. Also, there are no palm trees in the spiritual heaven.

**Likewise:**

The sheep (the righteous) and the goats ( the wicked) are said to be gathered before Jesus on his glorious throne. Clearly, all these nations are, not in heaven, but on earth. (Mt 25:31-32)

Matthew 25:31-32  (NASB)

The Judgment

> 31 “But when the Son of Man comes in His glory, and all the angels
> with Him, then He will sit on His glorious throne. 32 And all the
> nations will be gathered before Him; and He will separate them from
> one another, just as the shepherd separates the sheep from the goats;

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this question is in its very last line.

> … in heaven at this scene in Revelation 7:9

which mistakenly assumes that this verse is describing Heaven.

Look back a few verses earlier where the setting is established:

> After these things I saw four angels standing at the four corners of the **earth**, holding the four winds of the **earth**, that the wind should not blow on the **earth**, on the sea, or on any tree.

It's quite clear that what is being described is on Earth, not in Heaven.

Most of Revelation is a vision of the 1000 year Millennium, which happens here on Earth.

The various nations talked about in Revelation 7:9 are the remnant of the Earth's inhabitants that survive the Tribulation, not people that have died.

Comment: It would be nice if the people that downvoted this answer added a comment indicating why. ¶ Had they also downvoted Ozzie Ozzie's answer, I'd conclude it's because they disagree with its "*Clearly, all these nations are, not in heaven, but on earth*" and my "*what is being described is on Earth, not in Heaven*", but that's not the case. ¶ So if that's not what they disagree with, what *is* it that they didn't like?